# Import error for my compiled truffle contract in my app.js

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, solidity, web3js, truffle

I'm getting a compilation error

> "./src/App.js Module not found: You attempted to import
> ../../build/contracts/Lottery.json which falls outside of the project
> src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
> You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from
> project's node_modules/."

My project is using the react truffle box.

In my app.js I imported my Lottery.json file which is in my contract like this:

```
import Lottery from '../../build/contracts/Lottery.json';
```

I got the Lottery.json file in my build folder by running the truffle compile command

Any idea why my Lottery.json file is not being imported into my frontend?

[image]

Comment: It isn't imported because it lives outside of `client/src`. The last sentence in the blockquote that you shared hint on possible actions to remedy this.

Comment: https://maksimivanov.com/posts/ethereum-react-dapp-tutorial-part-2/